# Pockemon Go turned to Empty Map

Tags: android, intellij-idea, kotlin

I am working on android App using Kotlin Language that is similar to Pokemon Go,
There is no problems in the App  but when I installed it in my phone , only an empty Map is shown and the person is not going to my location How can I solve that ?

MapsActivity.tkt

```
package ahmedchtn.pockemontn

import android.content.Context
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.location.Location
import android.location.LocationListener
import android.location.LocationManager
import android.os.Build
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat
import android.widget.Toast

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptor
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions


class MapsActivity : FragmentActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    //WORK WITH USER LOCATION


    private var mMap: GoogleMap? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)


        checkPermmison()
        LoadPockemon()
    }

    var ACCESSLOCATION = 123
    fun checkPermmison() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {

            if (ActivityCompat.
                    checkSelfPermission(this,
                            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                requestPermissions(arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), ACCESSLOCATION)
                return
            }
        }

        GetUserLocation()
    }

    fun GetUserLocation() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "User location access on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        //TODO: Will implement later

        var myLocation = MylocationListener()

        var locationManager = getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 3, 3f, myLocation)

        var mythread = myThread()
        mythread.start()
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {

        when (requestCode) {

            ACCESSLOCATION -> {

                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    GetUserLocation()
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "We cannot access to your location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
        }

        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap


    }

    var location: Location? = null

    //Get user location

    inner class MylocationListener : LocationListener {


        constructor() {
            location = Location("Start")
            location!!.longitude = 0.0
            location!!.longitude = 0.0
        }

        override fun onLocationChanged(p0: Location?) {
            location = p0
        }

        override fun onStatusChanged(p0: String?, p1: Int, p2: Bundle?) {
            //TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        override fun onProviderEnabled(p0: String?) {
            // TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        override fun onProviderDisabled(p0: String?) {
            //TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

    }


    var oldLocation: Location? = null

    inner class myThread : Thread {

        constructor() : super() {
            oldLocation = Location("Start")
            oldLocation!!.longitude = 0.0
            oldLocation!!.longitude = 0.0
        }

        override fun run() {

            while (true) {

                try {

                    if (oldLocation!!.distanceTo(location) == 0f) {
                        continue
                    }

                    oldLocation = location


                    runOnUiThread {


                        mMap!!.clear()

                        // show me
                        val sydney = LatLng(location!!.latitude, location!!.longitude)
                        mMap!!.addMarker(MarkerOptions()
                                .position(sydney)
                                .title("Me")
                                .snippet(" here is my location")
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.naruto)))
                        mMap!!.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 14f))

                        // show pockemons

                        for (i in 0..listPockemons.size - 1) {

                            var newPockemon = listPockemons[i]

                            if (newPockemon.IsCatch == false) {

                                val pockemonLoc = LatLng(newPockemon.location!!.latitude, newPockemon.location!!.longitude)
                                mMap!!.addMarker(MarkerOptions()
                                        .position(pockemonLoc)
                                        .title(newPockemon.name!!)
                                        .snippet(newPockemon.des!! + ", power:" + newPockemon!!.power)
                                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(newPockemon.image!!)))


                                if (location!!.distanceTo(newPockemon.location) < 2) {
                                    newPockemon.IsCatch = true
                                    listPockemons[i] = newPockemon
                                    playerPower += newPockemon.power!!
                                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext,
                                            "You catch new pockemon your new pwoer is " + playerPower,
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                                }

                            }
                        }

                    }

                    Thread.sleep(1000)

                } catch (ex: Exception) {
                }


            }

        }

    }


    var playerPower = 0.0
    var listPockemons = ArrayList<Pockemon>()

    fun LoadPockemon() {


        listPockemons.add(Pockemon(R.drawable.charmandertn,
                "Charmander", "Charmander living in japan", 55.0, 35.687997, 10.085267))
        listPockemons.add(Pockemon(R.drawable.bulbasaurtn,
                "Bulbasaur", "Bulbasaur living in usa", 90.5, 35.687657, 10.084838))
        listPockemons.add(Pockemon(R.drawable.squirtletn,
                "Squirtle", "Squirtle living in iraq", 33.5, 35.687552, 10.084623))

    }

}
```

Pockemon.tkt

```
package ahmedchtn.pockemontn

import android.location.Location

/**
 * Created by Ahmed on 17-06-2017.
 */

class  Pockemon{
    var name:String?=null
    var des:String?=null
    var image:Int?=null
    var power:Double?=null
    var location:Location?=null
    var IsCatch:Boolean?=false
    constructor(image:Int,name:String,des:String,power:Double,lat:Double,log:Double){
        this.name=name
        this.des=des
        this.image=image
        this.power=power
        this.location= Location(name)
        this.location!!.latitude=lat
        this.location!!.longitude=log
        this.IsCatch=false
    }

}
```

AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ahmedchtn.pockemontn">
    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Check your permissions in settings - If the app does not have permission to use your location, it might show up blank.

Comment: I have added AndroidMAnifest in my question just now

Answer (score 0):

1. Get a Google Map Api key.
2. Make sure you select the Map template when creating your app.
3. After creating your app, change your app from debug to release.
4. Now go to `google_maps_api.xml` and insert your api key into a
   specified potion in the file that tells you to replace the
   "`google_maps_key`" there.

Rebuild and run your app. The map should be showing now.

To make the Pokemons show, Your `LoadPokemon()` function call should be in the `checkPermission(){}` function after `GetUserLocation()` and not in the `onCreate()` function.

Comment: I have done that , the map is shown but the Pokemons are not shown neither the player

Comment: I have found a problem with your code. Updating my answer soon.